# To check whether entered number is odd or even in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to check whether an entered number  is odd or even I am getting an error

```
declare 
num:=:num
if(num mod 2=0) then 
dbms_output.put_line(num|| 'is even');
else
dbms_output.put_line(num||' is odd');
end if;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if  'num mod 2' is the right way to write it. Use MOD( num, 2 ) and check. Also don't post a picture rather copy-paste the error message.

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you think `num mod 2=0` was the correct way to write your condition?

Comment: `num mod 2` is fine within procedural PL/SQL code (not SQL) - see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d991e4e28c548e838333f6affea63e9). The errors were because `num` is missing a datatype and needs to be terminated with a `;`,  and there should be a `begin` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the modulo function is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MOD.html#GUID-E12A3928-2C50-45B0-B8C3-82432C751B8C) which tells you the syntax is `MOD(n1, n2)` and not `n1 MOD n2` and you are missing the `BEGIN` statement:

You want:

```sql
declare 
  num:=:num
begin
  if mod(num, 2)=0 then 
    dbms_output.put_line(num|| 'is even');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line(num||' is odd');
  end if;
end;
```

You can simplify it by removing the intermediate variable and just using the bind variable throughout and can remove the `IF` statement and multiple output statements and use a single `CASE` (and handle `NULL` values):

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    :num || CASE MOD(:num, 2)
            WHEN 0 THEN ' is even'
            WHEN 1 THEN ' is odd'
            ELSE ' is neither odd nor even.'
            END
  );
END;
/
```